# Check SelectAll filtered records in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, filter, datagrid

How can I check all the records filtered by CheckAllBox event without using visible rows? (now it checks only the ones that visible on the screen).
this is the code behind:

```
    private void CheckAllBox_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){

        var grid = itemsGrid;
        VisibleRows = new List<string>();
        if (grid == null)
            return;
        //Getting the visible rows in dataGrid after filter
        foreach (var item in grid.Items)
        {
            var row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            if (row == null) continue;
            if (row.TransformToVisual(grid).Transform(new Point(0, 0)).Y + row.ActualHeight >= grid.ActualHeight) break;
            var item = (ItemParameter)row.DataContext;
            VisibleRows.Add(qdf.Qdf);
        }
        var vm = (ItemsPaneViewModel)DataContext;
        var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
        if (checkBox.IsChecked == null) return;
        var value = checkBox.IsChecked.Value;
        foreach (var ItemParameter in vm.ItemParameters)
        {

            if (VisibleRows.Contains(ItemParameter.Name))
                ItemParameter.IsEnable = value;
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's why i hardly recommend using MVVM when building a WPF application. You should have a look a the MVVM pattern. Would be very easy to check all checkboxes from your viewmodel.

Comment: We try to do how much as we can in the VM and turn to the code behind after exploring other options. this is not my code but I need to fix it to work not only with the visible items. If it's easy implementing it in VM, maybe you can show me how?

Comment: You could use a CollectionViewSource and a Filter to achive the filtering. Then your View will only show the filtered items and in your ViewModel you still have your whole list.